# AutoEmail based on Due date -_Reminder mail using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, reminders

[Snapshot of the google spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/701ZK.jpg)

```html
 function emailReminder() {
  
    //For testing purposes
    //You can view the log by typing CTRL+E after you run the script. 
  Logger.log(msg);
  
  // grab the Google Sheet object
  var googleSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // activates the first sheet
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(googleSheets.getSheets()[0]);
  // grabs the sheet
  var currentSheet = googleSheets.getActiveSheet();
  
  // find the last row
  var lastRow = currentSheet.getLastRow();
 
  // The first row starts at row 2 to account for headers
  var startRow = 2;
 
  // get E column data
  var range = currentSheet.getRange(2,5,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var remainingDays = range.getValues();
  
  // get A column data
  range = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  var columnA = range.getValues();
  
  // get D column data
  range = currentSheet.getRange(2, 4, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  var columnD = range.getValues();
  
  var count = 0;
  var msg = "";
  
  // Loop column E
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var daysLeft = remainingDays[i][0];
    if(daysLeft < 1) {
      // Checks to see if a cell value in column E less than 1
      var reminder = columnA[i][0];
      **var reminderdate = columnD[i][0];**
             
      msg = msg + "* Don't Forget: "+reminder+" is due on **"+reminderdate+"** which is "+daysLeft+" days.\n";
      count++;
    }
  }
  
   // Loop column E
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var daysLeft = remainingDays[i][0];
    if(daysLeft == 1) {
      // Checks to see if a cell value in column E equals 1
      var reminder = columnA[i][0];
       
      msg = msg + "Don't Forget: "+reminder+" is due tomorrow.\n";
      count++;
    }
  }
  // For multiple email addresses, use a comma to separate each email.
  if(count) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("yyy@gmai.com", 
        "Article Reminder", msg);
  }
   
}
```

The output is coming in email as

`Don't Forget:1231 is due onSun Feb 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 
(India Standard Time) which is -67 days.`

I want only the

```
Don't Forget:1231 is due on Sun Feb 09 2020 which is -67 days
```

to be reflecting in the output when the mail is sent.

Also, can the details be in table format which is not happening as of now when the mail is sent.(need to write the code for the same)

Comment: A new Query I want to add to this is the email id has to be picked up from spreadsheet..If there is blank then it must not send the particular task.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date you get from the Sheet so it only uses [dd-MM-yyyy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). To do so, use the [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) method and the Apps Script one [Utitilies.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format).

For example:

```
  var newDate = new Date(columnD[i][0]);
  var reminder = Utilities.formatDate(newDate, "IST", "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Then `reminder` will have the format like `11-Jan-2020`.